# How to convert a black and white video to a APNG file while setting a color as transparent?

Tags: ffmpeg, greenscreen, alpha

I created a small video with `threshold` filter to get black and white pixels (no greyscale):

```
ffmpeg -y -i /dev/video0
          -f lavfi -i color=0x606060:s=640x480
          -f lavfi -i color=black:s=640x480 -f lavfi
          -i color=white:s=640x480 -filter_complex threshold
          -c:v libx264 -c:a copy  test.mp4
```

Then I tried to convert it as a APNG file with white pixels as transparent (`chromakey` filter).

```
ffmpeg -y -i  test.mp4 -f apng -vf chromakey=white test.apng
```

This command converts all the pixels into transparent (checked with Gimp, it sets alpha of all pixels to 0).

Why? Also, how can I fix the command to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found how to do that in one `ffmpeg` command, using `colorkey`:

```
ffmpeg  -y -i /dev/video0
           -f lavfi -i color=0x6a6a6a:s=640x480
           -f lavfi -i color=black:s=640x480
           -f lavfi -i color=white:s=640x480
           -filter_complex 'threshold,colorkey=white'
           test.apng
```